# Getting blender camera fov or focal length from the unity3d camera fov

Tags: python, blender-internal-render-engine, camera, unity

I'm trying to match the fov of blender camera with unity 3d camera fov.
Basically i want to calculate blender's camera FOV or focal length, given the fov of unity3d camera.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the answer you needed, but in the properties bar under data and then under "Lens," they have a field that displays the camera's focal length

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately Blender's FOV interpretation seems to differ from Unity's. A same FOV camera doesn't have the same actual FOV between the programs